# GCP network setup

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, mpls

I am currently looking at GCP to use as an addition within our existing infrastructure. I am looking at trying to set up a vrf so I can keep this traffic isolated from my current setup, I can't find any documentation regarding vrfs or MPLS at all and was wondering if anyone has achieved this or gone down this path previously and can point me to any documentation or the reasons why this is not possible?

Many Thanks

Comment: Hi @a-doe, Can you share some more details about your current setup and what you imagine to be implemented with GCP products? It will help a lot to get an answer from experts. While the terms you mentioned including VRF and MPLS, are somewhat specific technical terms in basement, but in the cloud, we usually use virtual concepts and alternative terms, something like VPC for isolated network/space and Interconnect for enterprise grade hybrid network (inter link between data center and cloud VPC), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

VRF is one of famous solutions to make and provide an isolated network to clients(or users). But it lives on provider's half and not user's half in cloud world. VPC is an abstracted concept of isolated network and the only thing users need to care. I mean, the terms MPLS and VRF are part of the layer 2 and 3 and which are not used in Google Cloud Platform since those are managed by Google ISP.

However, GCP uses other concepts/components in order to get a isolation network. Assuming that you want to extend your on-prem network which has VRFs to GCP, from a very high level you can create multiple VPC networks in GCP (each VPC network can be thought of as a VRF on GCP side) and then use Cloud Router - VLAN attachment per VPC network to connect to on-prem side which advertises subnets and propagates learned routes in the region where the router is configured or throughout the entire VPC network.

Additionally, please note that the VPC network can be connected to on-prem using a VPN connection. So, talking about a VPC network, those are "isolated" to customers by virtue of being in different projects.  One customer's VMs in their VPC network cannot connect to another customer's VMs in a different VPC network, unless the two VPC networks are connected using something like VPC peering (which requires Network Admin authorization for each VPC network) or by creating VPN tunnels to connect the two VPC networks.

Please take a look at the following links:
[Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/)
[Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) Network Overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc)